# How could I show a popup alert message after sending mail from contact form using AJAX & PHP?

Tags: php, ajax, email, contact-form

I have a contact form in a web page. Here I'm sending mail throwing ajax request in php mailer. Now if I want to show a alert message depending on message send or not then what should I do?

Here is my code, which is not showing the success alert at all.

**AJAX Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-btn').click(function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'JSON',
            url: 'mail-process.php', //PHP Mail Code Page location
            type: 'POST', //Form Method
            data: $('#contact').serialize(), //Form ID
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.txt').html('SENDING...');
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('.txt').html('SEND MESSAGE');
            },
            success: function() {
                $('#msg').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Message successfuly Sent.</div>');
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#msg').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Please Fillup Properly, and Try Again.</div>');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My mail is successfully delivered, But it not working the success & error condition at all. How Could I Fix it?

Comment: If you want to know if it failed or not in your Ajax code, then your PHP needs to return that state and you need to check it in your Ajax success-response. Please show us the PHP-code.

Comment: Side note: If you are using this code to send email, remember to disable the submit button after user clicked it. Otherwise, your user is able to click many times, and the emails will be sent repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

First, please check your CSS file if it is hiding the alert div or not. If so, you should remove that.

Anyway, I recommend to place the alert div into #msg, not to create them when your ajax succeeds.

Let them invisible with using `display:none`, and show one of them after ajax runs.

```
<div id="msg">
   <div class="alert alert-success" style="display:none">Message successfuly Sent.</div>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">Please Fillup Properly, and Try Again.</div>
</div>
```

And edit your javascript code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submit-btn').click(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: 'mail-process.php', //PHP Mail Code Page location
        type: 'POST', //Form Method
        data: $('#contact').serialize(), //Form ID
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.txt').html('SENDING...');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('.txt').html('SEND MESSAGE');
        },
        success: function() {
            $('.alert-success').show();
        },
        error: function() {
            $('.alert-danger').show();
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: This does not fix the issue. It's just another way to show the alert message.